# Alinear texto dentro de un menú desplegable

Tags: html, css

Estoy creando la barra de navegación para una web, y quería hacer un menú desplegable pero llevo horas intentando averiguar por que no consigo que se me alinee el texto del siguiente desplegable, he probado con text-align: center y no logro que se vea centrado, y ya no se si es que el código de mi css está mal, o mi html...  No se si algunos apartados de mi código css están interfiriendo entre ellos y por eso no me cambia nada.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dejo por aqui el html y el css para ver si me pueden ayudar a encontrar el fallo.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">


        <link rel="stylesheet" href="pruebadesp.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="interior">
                <p class="logo"><a href="#">Saving Paws</a><p>
                <nav class="navegacion">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Quiénes somos</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Colabora</a></li>
                        <li><a href="fotosAnimales.php">Adopta</a></li>
                        <li class="submenu">
                            <a href="">Mi área</a>
                            <ul class="hijos">
                                <li><a href="">Mi perfil</a></li>
                                <li><a href="login.php">Iniciar sesión</a></li>
                                <li><a href="html.php">Registrarse</a></li>

                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>

        </header>

        <!-- Footer -->

        <footer>
            <h3>Saving Paws</h3>
        </footer>

    </body>
</html>
```

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300);
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Balsamiq+Sans&display=swap');

*{
    margin: 0; /*elimina margenes x defecto de html*/
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: "Roboto";
}
body{
    background: white;
    height: 100%
}
header{/*modifica la base de la cabecera*/
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: #f6b075;
    
     
}
.interior{/*es el ancho del primero*/
   width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    background: #f6b075;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0 10px; /*se va mas a la derecha*/
    
}
.interior .logo{ /*modifica el recuadro del logo*/
    width: 30%;
    height: 70px;
    float: left;
    background: #f6b075;
    padding-top: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box; /*se ajusta al ancho d la caja*/ 
  
}


.interior .logo a { /*modifica el texto (logo)*/

    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-family: 'Balsamiq Sans';
    text-decoration: none; /*quita el subrayado*/
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    padding: 0 180px;
    
}

.navegacion{/*caja*/
    float: right;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 1000;
    background: #f6b075;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-top: 24px;
    
}


.navegacion ul{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0 150px;
     box-sizing: border-box; 
}


.navegacion ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    transition: .3s linear;
    z-index: 1000;
     box-sizing: border-box; 
     
    
     
}


.navegacion ul li:hover{
    color: #656565;
    transform: scale(1.1);
}


.navegacion ul li a{/*modifica todos los A dentro de ul y li*/
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase; 
    padding: 12px 20px;
    transition: .3s linear;
    text-decoration: none; 
    
     padding-left: 40px; /*espacio entre li*/
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    
}




.navegacion ul li a:hover{
    color: #656565;
   
}
.navegacion ul li:hover .hijos{
    display: block;
}



.navegacion .submenu .hijos{ /*caja contenedora del desplegable*/
    display: none;
    background: #f6b075;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    

}


.navegacion .submenu .hijos li{/*txt del desplegable*/
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-bottom: none;
    
    
}



.navegacion .submenu .hijos li a{
    display: block;
    
      
}




/*pie de pagina*/
footer {
    background: #f6b075;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    clear:both;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    align-self: flex-end;
}


footer h3 {
    font-family: "Balsamiq Sans";
    color: white;
   text-align: center;
   /* centrar vertical y horizontalmente */
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   margin: -25px 0 0 -25px; /* aplicar a top y al margen izquierdo un valor negativo para completar el centrado del elemento hijo */
}

/*-------*/
```

[image: Me gustaría que quedase algo así, es decir centrado o a la izquierda.]

Comment: Podrías subir una imagen de como quieres que quede? Puedes dibujarlo en Paint, es solo para tener una idea.

Comment: @Fedex7501 listo

Comment: Algo así? https://codepen.io/fedex75/pen/LYevoeJ

Comment: @Fedex7501 Si!! Muchas gracias! ponlo como respuesta si quieres :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nuevo CSS:

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300);
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Balsamiq+Sans&display=swap');

*{
    margin: 0; /*elimina margenes x defecto de html*/
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: "Roboto";
}
body{
    background: white;
    height: 100%
}
header{/*modifica la base de la cabecera*/
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: #f6b075;
    
     
}
.interior{/*es el ancho del primero*/
   width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    background: #f6b075;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0 10px; /*se va mas a la derecha*/
    
}
.interior .logo{ /*modifica el recuadro del logo*/
    width: 30%;
    height: 70px;
    float: left;
    background: #f6b075;
    padding-top: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box; /*se ajusta al ancho d la caja*/ 
  
}


.interior .logo a { /*modifica el texto (logo)*/

    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-family: 'Balsamiq Sans';
    text-decoration: none; /*quita el subrayado*/
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    padding: 0 180px;
    
}

.navegacion{/*caja*/
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 1000;
    background: #f6b075;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-top: 24px;
    padding-right: 60px;
}


.navegacion ul{
    list-style: none;
    
     box-sizing: border-box; 
}


.navegacion ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    transition: .3s linear;
    z-index: 1000;
     box-sizing: border-box; 
     
    
     
}


.navegacion ul li:hover{
    color: #656565;
    transform: scale(1.1);
}


.navegacion ul li a{/*modifica todos los A dentro de ul y li*/
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase; 
    padding: 12px 20px;
    transition: .3s linear;
    text-decoration: none; 
    
     padding-left: 40px; /*espacio entre li*/
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    
}




.navegacion ul li a:hover{
    color: #656565;
   
}
.navegacion ul li:hover .hijos{
    display: block;
}



.navegacion .submenu .hijos{ /*caja contenedora del desplegable*/
    display: none;
    background: #f6b075;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    

}


.navegacion .submenu .hijos li{/*txt del desplegable*/
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-bottom: none;
    
    
}



.navegacion .submenu .hijos li a{
    display: block;
    
      
}




/*pie de pagina*/
footer {
    background: #f6b075;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    clear:both;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    align-self: flex-end;
}


footer h3 {
    font-family: "Balsamiq Sans";
    color: white;
   text-align: center;
   /* centrar vertical y horizontalmente */
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   margin: -25px 0 0 -25px; /* aplicar a top y al margen izquierdo un valor negativo para completar el centrado del elemento hijo */
}

.submenu {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    align-items: center;
}
```